# Python Numpy Matplotlib Set Y-Label inline

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, plot

I'm wondering how I might set the Y label in the following plot all inline with one another. Currently they are misaligned since the Y values are not of equal space.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, it's probably easier to not use the `ylabel` at all.  Instead, use `annotate` to place the text at a constant offset from the left side of the axes.

As an example of your problem:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, sharex=True)
yranges = [(-1000, 100), (-0.001, 0.002), (0, 5), (0, 20)]
labels = ['$P_{EUC}[mm]$', '$P_z[mm]$', '$P_Y[mm]$', '$P_X[mm]$']

for ax, yrange, label in zip(axes, yranges, labels):
    ax.set(ylim=yrange, ylabel=label)

plt.show()
```

[image]

To solve this, it's easiest to use `annotate`.  The trick is to position the text at `y=0.5` in *axes* coordinates, and then *5 points* from the left hand edge of the figure in the x-direction.  The syntax is a bit verbose, but is relatively easy to read.  The key is in the `xycoords` and `textcoords` kwargs that control how `xy` and `xytext` are interpreted:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=4, sharex=True)
yranges = [(-1000, 100), (-0.001, 0.002), (0, 5), (0, 20)]
labels = ['$P_{EUC}[mm]$', '$P_z[mm]$', '$P_Y[mm]$', '$P_X[mm]$']

for ax, yrange, label in zip(axes, yranges, labels):
    ax.set(ylim=yrange)
    ax.annotate(label, xy=(0, 0.5), xytext=(5, 0), rotation=90,
                xycoords=('figure fraction', 'axes fraction'),
                textcoords='offset points', va='center', ha='left')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#align-my-ylabels-across-multiple-subplots You can muck with the ylabels with out having to resort to annotate ;)

Comment: @tcaswell - Nice! Didn't know about that method!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this more elegantly with `ax.yaxis.set_label_coords`, using a constant value for the x coordinate, as shown [here](http://matplotlib.org/faq/howto_faq.html#align-my-ylabels-across-multiple-subplots). For your example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

labels = ['$P_{EUC}[mm]$', '$P_z[mm]$', '$P_Y[mm]$', '$P_X[mm]$']

fig,axs=plt.subplots(4,1,sharex=True)

axs[0].set_ylim(-1000,0)
axs[1].set_ylim(-0.0010,0.0020)
axs[2].set_ylim(0,5)
axs[3].set_ylim(0,20)

[axs[i].set_ylabel(labels[i]) for i in range(4)]

labelx = -0.1 # Change this to suit your needs
[axs[i].yaxis.set_label_coords(labelx,0.5) for i in range(4)]

fig.savefig('labelx.png')
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can offset x and y labels using the set_ylabel method on the AxesSubplots.
http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=y%20label#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_ylabel

You can also format the y tick mark labels. http://matplotlib.org/api/axes_api.html?highlight=y%20label#matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_yticklabels

When working with matplotlib text objects, you can use the argument  `transform=ax.transAxes` to use `Figure` coordinates instead of `Axes` coordinates if you want to loop through the subfigures.

But I think what you're looking for is just to offset them. When the docs are sparse, use `dir()` to poke through the namespace.

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1, 1)
```

`dir(ax)` includes `yaxis`.

`dir(ax.yaxis)` includes `get_label`.

`dir(ax.yaxis.get_label())` includes `set_x`.

`help(ax.yaxis.get_label().set_x` says:

```
set_x(self, x) method of matplotlib.text.Text instance
    Set the *x* position of the text

    ACCEPTS: float
```

Comment: Is there no automatic way though to offset the x and y labels such that they are equally spaced. I would not like to do this for every plot

Comment: I'm tinkering with this and `ax.yaxis.get_label().set_x` doesn't appear to work. `get_label()` might return the text from the *legend* rather than the axis label. I have some code in which I successfully styled the y axis labels with `ax.yaxis.label.set_family('Georgia')` but `ax.yaxis.label.set_x(0)` isn't working for me to achieve your request either. :-(

Comment: Oddly, I can get translation of y-axis labels using `ax.yaxis.get_label().set_verticalalignment('bottom'|'top)` . Positions appear to be in the frame of the characters; "up" is toward the top of the letters, i.e. to the left. But I haven't achieved offset further to the left.